# Why is the infinitive of "fero" "ferre" and not "ferse"?

Tags: etymology

The 'r' in Latin infinitive endings "-are", "-ere", "-ĕre" and "-ire" is explained as coming from Proto-Indo-European 's', by 's' turning to 'r' in Latin between two vowels. So, the Proto-Indo-European infinitive ending was -se. But, if so, why is the infinitive of "fero" (to bear, from *b<sup>h</sup>er) "fer-re" and not "fer-se"? "-rs-" obviously existed in Latin, as in "cu**rs**or" (runner).

Comment: Often consonants like that get elided. For example, instead of adsumo sometimes you see assumo.

Comment: @TylerDurden That's not elision but assimilation.

Comment: Also Proto-Indo-European is not reconstructed to have infinitive form of verbs. Infinitives in daughter languages developed from various nouns or adjectives (participles) related to verbs. E.g. Proto-Germanic [\*-ną](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/-aną) developed from PIE \*-nóm (accusative of [\*-nós](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-nós) adjective),

Comment: Proto-Slavic [\*-ti](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/-ti) developed from PIE \*-téi̯ (dative or locative of [\*-tis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-tis) noun), Latin [*-ere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ere#Latin) (Old Latin *-esi* [-ɛzi]) and Ancient Greek [*-ειν*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ειν#Ancient_Greek) developed from variants of locative of PIE athematic [\*-os](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-os) noun,

Comment: and Sanskrit [*-तुम्* (*-tum*)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-तुम्#Sanskrit) developed from PIE \*-tum (accusative of [\*-tus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-tus) noun; also ancestor of Latin *supīnum*).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was a regular sound change PIt. (= Proto-Italic) *-rs- > Lat. -rr-, or rather PIt. *-Rs- > Lat. -RR- where R stands for a liquid (/r/ or /l/). Examples (from Weiss *Hist. Comp. Gram. Lat.* 1st ed. p. 171) include *terreō* vs. Umb. *tursitu* 'terrify', *collum* vs. Goth. *hals* 'neck'.

You're right of course that the sequence -rs- (and likewise -ls-) does exist in Latin, but it is secondary, i.e. derived from something other than *-rs-: namely, *-Rss- and *-RCs- both gave -Rs-, e.g. *versus* < *vorssos, *mulsī* < *mulksī.

The case of *cursus* specifically (from which *cursor* is derived) is more complicated because that would have had *-r̥st- (*kr̥s-tos), which doesn't yield Lat. -rs- by regular sound change; apparently the participle was reformed with *-sus* under the influence of forms like *versus*, where -rs- is regular (< *-rss- < *-rt-t).